# How to check the memory and space of MarkLogic cluster?

Tags: marklogic

Is there a query which can be used by which we can get/calculate the memory/space details of MarkLogic server?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Monitoring History if you are looking for CPU. Mem, and other MarkLogic specific statistics. Period selection `Raw` gives you minutely information all the way back to 7 days ago, unless you have altered Meters settings in the Admin UI.

You can also gather information yourself. It is mostly driven from functions like `xdmp:host-status`, and `xdmp:forest-status`, but it conveniently gathers this info for you in the background, giving you a historic perspective as well.

There are also [memory consumption log messages](https://help.marklogic.com/knowledgebase/article/View/527/0/memory-consumption-logging-and-status) logged in the ErrorLog.txt detailing memory use broken out by major areas is periodically recorded to the error log. These diagnostic messages can be useful for quickly identifying memory resource consumption at a glance and aid in determining where to investigate memory-related issues.

HTH!